# Print post title with markup

Tags: title

I have a piece of code that outputs my post title but how can I output it as an H4?

Here is the code I have: `<?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ); ?>`
Thanks

Comment: You can do: `<h4><?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ); ?></h4>`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I had already tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Try `the_title()` as suggested in the answer. That way, though, you wouldn't be able to set the post ID the same way you could set it with `get_the_title()`.

Comment: @dan2017 when you say it didn't work, can you be more specific?  What does the surrounding code look like? Does it display anything at all? Does it show the title without the h4 when you use your current code? And which file is this in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example, you could...

```
<h4><?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ); ?></h4>
```

Or

```
$h4 = get_the_title();
echo '<h4>' . $h4 . '</h4>';
```

More on [get_the_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/).

Or you could use [the_title()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title).

```
the_title( '<h4>', '</h4>' );
```

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way is:

```
<h4><?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ); ?></h4>
```

However, if you want check first if that post *has* a title and avoid an empty `<h4>` if it doesn't, you write:

```
$title = get_the_title( $post_id );

if ( $title )
    echo "<h4>$title</h4>";
```